# How Can I Auth Login After Changing Users Table Column names?

Tags: laravel, authentication

after I changed user table name and columns auth attempts returns false even though credentials are true. I also changed config/auth.php. But still user can not login the system. Where should I change? Can you give me an idea?

My Auth Controller is

```html
<?php

class YetkiController extends Controller
{
    public function Login()
    {
        return view('sayfalar.GirisYap');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {  
        $request['password'] = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $credidentials = ['eposta'=>  $request['email'], 'sifre'=>  $request['password']];
        dd(Auth::attempt($credidentials));
    
    }
    }
```

My User model is Kullanici.php

```html
 
class Kullanici extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
    public $table = 'kullanicilar';
    protected $fillable = [
        'isim_soyisim',
        'eposta',
        'sifre',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'sifre',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'eposta_dogrulama' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

auth.php

```html
<?php

return [

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\kullanici::class,
        ],
    ],

    'table' => 'kullanicilar',
```

Comment: Have you checked the result of `bcrypt($request['password'])`? Is it the same as the password that was stored for the user?

Comment: when passing credentials to `attempt` the password field **MUST** be named `password` (this does not relate to the name in the database) all the other fields passed in the credentials are just `where` conditions on the query ... you can tell the model which field is the password field by overriding the `getAuthPassword` method on your model to return the model's password

Comment: @lagbox, I solved my problem by changing $credentials['password'] as $credentials['sifre'] at Auth/UserProvider classes. Is there any way?

Comment: you should **not** be altering the user providers ... you only need to adjust the model

Answer (score 1):

You can simply not use `Auth::attempt()` and do it yourself

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request['password'] = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = $this->user->where('eposta', strtolower($request['email']))->first();

    if ($user && app('hash')->check($request['password'], $user->password)) {
        Auth::login($user);
        //redirect to logged in page
        return redirect()->to('dashboard'); 
    } else {
        //return back with error
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->input())
            ->withErrors('login or password incorrect');
    }
}
```